# C# how to resolve a GUID to a folder path?

Tags: c#, directory, path, guid

I'm using some com objects and the path returned is `::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Documents.library-ms`.

Is there a C# function that can automatically resolve this to its normal path

`C:\Users\my pc\Documents`?

`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` does not work.

Comment: Well normally you would use [`SHGetPathFromIDList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlista) but the path you mentioning looks more like a shell namespace prefix with a regular string attached to it

Comment: It was returned from powershell using `$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application` and `$shell.windows().item(0).document.folder.self.path` with my explorer window being on Library\Documents